# DB2 function error

Tags: function, db2

What's wrong with the following DB2 function?

```
CREATE FUNCTION MIGRATION.determineToTaxService
(DIGI_NAAR_VLG CHAR, DIGI_VAN_VLG CHAR, NAARVLG CHAR)
RETURNS CHAR
BEGIN ATOMIC
    DECLARE returnValue CHAR;
    SET returnValue = '0';

    IF (DIGI_NAAR_VLG = '1') THEN
        SET returnValue = '1';

    ELSEIF (DIGI_VAN_VLG = '1') THEN
        SET returnValue = '1';

    ELSEIF (NAARVLG = '1') THEN
        SET returnValue = '1';
    END IF;

    RETURN returnValue;
END;
```

I'm getting this error:

```
An unexpected token "CHAR" was found following " DECLARE returnValue".  Expected tokens may   include:  "END-OF-STATEMENT". SQL Code: -104, SQL State: 42601
Error occured in:
CREATE FUNCTION MIGRATION.determineToTaxService
   (DIGI_NAAR_VLG CHAR, DIGI_VAN_VLG CHAR,
    NAARVLG CHAR)
RETURNS CHAR
BEGIN ATOMIC
    DECLARE returnValue CHAR
```

I can't really figure it out. It's also not running if I remove the if and elsif statements so the problem shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1):

The terminating character is wrong:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MIGRATION.determineToTaxService
(DIGI_NAAR_VLG CHAR, DIGI_VAN_VLG CHAR, NAARVLG CHAR)
RETURNS CHAR
BEGIN ATOMIC
    DECLARE returnValue CHAR;
    SET returnValue = '0';

    IF (DIGI_NAAR_VLG = '1') THEN
        SET returnValue = '1';

    ELSEIF (DIGI_VAN_VLG = '1') THEN
        SET returnValue = '1';

    ELSEIF (NAARVLG = '1') THEN
        SET returnValue = '1';
    END IF;

    RETURN returnValue;
END @
```

You can call it from the command line like:

```
db2 -td@ -vf test
```

Comment: I know, but the database which I have to migrate works with chars so I also have to work with them. using CHAR(1) in the params and declarations gives me: An unexpected token ")" was found following "E returnValue CHAR(1".

Comment: Are you running that from command line? what is the terminating character for the function? because it cannot be ';'

Comment: I'm using squirrel. I've tried @ and ; after the "END" statement.

Comment: My previous answer was wrong. DB2 accept CHAR without size (I did not know). However, your problem is the terminator char. I already tested with the @ at the end, and it works.

Comment: Hmm.. Could squirrel be the problem? That would actually suprise me! Thanks for running it btw. Now I know the problem isn't my script.

Comment: You need to specify statement terminator as @ in squirrel, I think it is under session somewhere. I'll add another solution as a possible answer though

Answer (score 1):

A trick is to end the lines with a comment like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MIGRATION.determineToTaxService
    (DIGI_NAAR_VLG CHAR, DIGI_VAN_VLG CHAR, NAARVLG CHAR)
RETURNS CHAR
BEGIN ATOMIC
    DECLARE returnValue CHAR; --
    SET returnValue = '0'; --

    IF (DIGI_NAAR_VLG = '1') THEN
        SET returnValue = '1'; --

    ELSEIF (DIGI_VAN_VLG = '1') THEN
        SET returnValue = '1'; --

    ELSEIF (NAARVLG = '1') THEN
        SET returnValue = '1'; --
    END IF; --

    RETURN returnValue; --
END ;
```

Then you can continue using ; as a statement terminator

You might want to simplify the function, something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MIGRATION.determineToTaxService
    (DIGI_NAAR_VLG CHAR, DIGI_VAN_VLG CHAR, NAARVLG CHAR)
RETURNS CHAR
RETURN
    CASE WHEN DIGI_NAAR_VLG = '1' THEN '1'
         WHEN DIGI_VAN_VLG = '1' THEN '1'
         WHEN NAARVLG = '1' THEN '1'
         ELSE '0'
    END
```

should do

Comment: The first statement still gives me `An unexpected token "CHAR" was found following "DECLARE returnValue".  Expected tokens may include:  "END-OF-STATEMENT".` The second function works because there is no `BEGIN` statement in it.